# XAML Datagrid (WPFToolkit) remove empty space and resize

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, resize

i have a datatable imported into a Datagrid, i have installed a WPFToolkit.

my code xaml is:

`<Window x:Class="ToolQueryLog.ResultShow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    Title="ResultShow" Background="Turquoise" FontSize="15" Width="Auto" Closed="Window_Closed">
<my:DataGrid  Width="auto" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="dataGrid1" />
</Window>`.

The c# code for bind is:

`dataGrid1.DataContext = result.DefaultView;`

my windows result is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QNV1.png)

and i'll need this window:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00hsh.png)

any idea?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your window set the `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` This will automatically resize the window to the dimensions of your `DataGrid`

Comment: Fantastic , thanks a lot , fast and efficient solution